# How to move the legend of each trace inside each subplot when subplot has more than 1 column

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

When subplot has 2 columns and 2 rows. Typically the legends are grouped together and places on the same location like below on the right hand side. I am wondering if I can place legend of each trace inside each of subplot, for example, legend of Trace 1 inside subplot row=1 and col=1, legend of trace 2 inside subplot row=1, col=2?  Thanks

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
# Create subplots with the shared legend
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2, subplot_titles=("Plot 1", "Plot 2", "Plot 3", "Plot 4"))
# Add traces to subplots
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 4, 1, 3, 5, 2], y=[4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 2], name="Trace 1"), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5], y=[7, 8, 9, 3, 2, 6], name="Trace 2"), row=1, col=2)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[3, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6], y=[1, 3, 5, 4, 2, 3], name="Trace 3"), row=2, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3, 2, 6, 4], y=[3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 1], name="Trace 4"), row=2, col=2)
# Update layout for customized legend grouping
fig.update_layout(legend=dict(tracegroupgap=70))
# Show the plot
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a [`legendgroup`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/scatter/#scatter-legendgroup) for each trace, one group per row, otherwise `tracegroupgap` has no effect, eg.

```py
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[...], y=[...], name="Trace 1", legendgroup='group 1'), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[...], y=[...], name="Trace 2", legendgroup='group 1'), row=1, col=2)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[...], y=[...], name="Trace 3", legendgroup='group 2'), row=2, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[...], y=[...], name="Trace 4", legendgroup='group 2'), row=2, col=2)
```

The problem then - if you need the figure to be responsive - is that the gap should be relative to the plot's height but you can only specify an absolute value (px), so you would have to set that gap using some javascript instead (ie. using a `plotly_relayout` handler). If you set a fixed height for the layout though, it should be fine.